# Can we initialize a global final variable with value from databag

Tags: java, cron, final, databags

I have to schedule a method with @Scheduled Annotation which only takes a constant variable as a parameter. But I want this constant to be initialized from a databag instead of hard coding it. Is there a way to do it?

I can you timer and it works but I want to know if this is possible.I have tried initializing the variable in PostConstruct annotation but it didn't work either as final variables has to be initialized at declaration

```
   static final int t ;
   @Scheduled(fixedDelay = t)
   public void pushToSearchPeriodic(){
       publishSearchMessagesAndFlush();
   }
```

need to avoid hard code variable t.

Comment: No: annotations are compile-time beings and you can't feed a runtime value into one

Comment: I figured that. I needed to know if its possible to initialize a final variable from a value from databag or database

Comment: Yes (and also, you don't want to do that), but then you can't use that value in an annotation because it's no longer a "constant expression".